# jq filter expression in string interpolation

Tags: json, jq, string-interpolation

I have been trying to reduce the array to a string to be used in string interpolation.

For example.

```
input = ["123", "456"]
expected output = array=123,456
```

Here is my try

```
$ echo '["123", "456"]' | jq 'array=\(.|join(","))'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
array=\(.|join(","))
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: There's no string in your filter to interpolate into.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using string interpolation `\(.)`, you can do something like below. Your idea is almost right, but interpolation using `\(..)` needs the filter to present be inside a string with the expression to be used defined inside parens after a backslash

```
jq --raw-output '"array=\(join(","))"'
```

Comment: thanks! was having a hard time understanding this (or i have clocked out for the day) via the manual.

Comment: The interesting point here is that the double-quotes inside the `\(....)` construct should not be escaped.  These escaped expressions can also be nested, and the same rule about not having to escape double-quotes applies within such expressions as well, e.g. `jq -n '"\("a\("x")")"`

Comment: You can find this in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) under the heading `String interpolation`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '["123", "456"]' | jq -r '"array=" + join(",")'
```